# Does a mobile plugged in to the charger produce more EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation, mobile-phones

I've been hearing this a lot lately, but I can't seem to find anything to disprove (or prove) this claim. I know that a weak signal means the phone produces more radiation (which makes sense), but a lot of people I know constantly talk about how using a mobile phone *while it is being charged* is dangerous, because when you plug it in it produces a lot more radiation.

Perhaps it's an extension of [this rumor](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13807/does-a-cell-phone-emit-1000-times-more-radiation-when-its-battery-is-low/13816#13816) about low battery causing a similar effect. Also, note I'm not talking about the dangers of the phone exploding or anything like that, because while that does happen, it seems that those are most probably related to [counterfeited phones](http://wafflesatnoon.com/2014/02/02/cell-phone-charging-dangers/) of questionable quality.

Comment: Removed a pointless bickering about radiation (and fixed the question for the doubters).

Comment: I've also had to remove 2 answers which were theoretical in nature. The point of this question is to know whether the EM radiation changes and in which direction (increase, decrease).
We all know that there are power saving features. The point is whether this has any noticeable effect based on the plugged in/plugged off variable. In other words, the mechanism by which this claim *could* be true is secondary. First you need to establish there *is* an effect, otherwise any explanation is pure fantasy.

Comment: Moderation note: we've left time and asked the OPs of those questions to fix, but once multiple theoretical answers started to appear and comments started degenerating into a theoretical debate, we decided to delete the posts until they are fixed. We understand deletion is never a good experience and apologise in advance for that, but the site has specific rules for answers which need to be enforced.

Comment: Since this question seems to attract a lot of theoretical answers (at least 6 so far), further theoretical answers will be deleted more quickly.